# Grid misaligned with parent Div on programmatic scroll

Tags: html, css, dojo, css-position, dgrid

I have the html layout the following way

```
<div id="tab-container"> <!--(position = absolute) -->
    <div id="contentpane"> <!--//(position = absolute)-->
       <div id="dgrid"> <!--//(position = relative)-->
          <div id = "grid-header"> <!--//(position= absolute)--> </div>
              <div id="grid-content"> <!--//(overflow:auto; margin-top:50px;position:absolute)--> </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I have problem scrolling through the grid results, when ever i scroll to a result programmatically, the grid is going out of parent div and not positioned properly. I don't see the header showing up. 
I tried with different positioning of div, but not able to figure out the root cause. What could be causing this?

Comment: Wrong line comments!!! use `<!-- -->` for HTML

Comment: Please provide a snippet or jsfiddle for proper debugging. Currently, it's impossible to see what the issue is without guessing.